# Simplest way to run ruby CGI app

Tags: ruby, cgi

What is the simplest way to run locally a Ruby CGI app

I am looking for a very simple e.g. 5 lines of code if possible way without using external servers  such as NginX and Apache etc

**EDIT:**

To be more precise:

Given a simple Ruby script I would like to serve it as CGI, either by requiring a Gem within it or by using another tiny .rb script.

By serve as CGI I mean to be able to interact with it using my web browser

Comment: Does it have to be a true CGI app, or are you just looking to make a simple Ruby web app?

Comment: Simplest CGI app, I woul like to teach plan Ruby CGI to someone.
I am not looking for Sinatra etc.

Comment: I think what Matthew means is, do you just want to write a ruby app that you can point a browser at, or do you want it to be CGI - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface ?

Comment: CGI requires a webserver like Nginx or Apache, so your question doesn't make sense. Besides, you can run a standalone server in Sinatra with about 5 lines of code, so I'm not sure why you are eliminating that.

Comment: @MarkThomas, it requires a web-server.  But that server could certainly be simpler (albeit less production-ready) than Nginx or Apache.  The Python standard library has a dead-simple CGI server called [`CGIHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.server#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler).

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something similar/similarly simple like Python's CGIHTTPRequestHandler

Comment: There's the [cgiup](http://rubygems.org/gems/cgiup) library.

Comment: @MarkThomas, interesting.  That really answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ gem install cgiup

$ cgiup ruby_cgi_script.rb
```

Comment: Note that cgiup simply wraps WEBrick's CGI handler: https://github.com/ryanbriones/cgiup/blob/master/bin/cgiup so it's easy to customize.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not married to a particular webserver and don't need a ton of volume, you can set up and run [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) with its standalone Webrick server in about five lines of code.

CGI proper will require more setup, however the Lighttpd web server is relatively simple to configure for Ruby CGI.  The only things you have to add to lighttpd.conf are:

```
server.modules  += ( "mod_cgi" )
cgi.assign = (
    ".rb"  => "/usr/local/bin/ruby" # or whatever your path to Ruby is
)
```

Comment: I think you didn't read my question properly and/or comments. Your answer probably deserves down-voting, please do not litter SO.

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't what you were looking for, I answered before your question was clarified.